# IE8 Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, icefaces-3

I have a problem with Icefaces 3.0.0.GA
in my application after i click on ice:comandlink in IE8 and IE 9 in javascript debbuger I get message that: Object doesn't support this property or method in function

```
function registerElementListener(element, eventType, listener) {
    var previousListener = element[eventType];
    if (previousListener) {
        element[eventType] = function(e) {
            var args = [e];
            previousListener.apply(element, args);
            listener.apply(element, args);
        };
    } else {
        element[eventType] = listener;
    }
}
```

and than i refresh the page it's working but after some time i get this message again.I think the problem with  previousListener.apply(element, args);
What can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what the eventType is when you have this issue?  Could it be that it's an event that IE8 doesn't support?  Also, one would seriously ask why this code is trying to reinvent `.addEventListener()` and `.attachEvent()` as they already solve the issue of multiple event handlers for the same event.

Comment: here is my xhtm:  <ice:panelSeries id="icePnlSrs" 
      value="#{eITConfigurationPopup.AConfigurationList}"
      var="configuration" style="float:left" >  <ice:commandLink style="color: #175097; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px" value="#{configuration.ADesignation}" partialSubmit="true" actionListener="#{eITConfigurationPopup.mSelectConfigPic}" >
        <f:param name="ConfigId" value="#{configuration.AId}"></f:param>
       </ice:commandLink>

Comment: Please don't put long multiline xhtml in a comment.  Use the edit button to add it to your question where it can be formatted in a readable fashion.

Comment: If it is working when you refresh, then we need to know how the page with `panelSeries` is rendered. It's most likely that some component is losing its state probably during ajax render because that's the way icefaces works and behind the scenes there's lot of things going on, you might need to dig into the source code of Icefaces, somewhere in the component renderer class.